# Cant install edge with npm for node js

Tags: node.js, installation, edgejs

I'm trying to install edge for Node.js but when I type npm install edge it downloads the packages but just says  "node tools/install.js" and does nothing. I can see the downloaded files in C:/Users/XXX/AppData/Roaming/npm-cache.

Any help?